# Css style dont pass to label inside form

Tags: css

I have form:

```
<form class="userForm">
...
</form>
```

inside of this form is `fieldset` then `div` and inside of div is `label`. Now I want to create css to all label inside of this form:

I try this:

```
form.userform label {
    width: 150px;
}
```

but with no success

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your capitalization. Change your form classname to `userform` **or** use the following CSS:

This should work:

```
form.userForm label {
  width: 150px;
}
```

And also this should work (like Girish suggested earlier):

```
.userForm label {
  width: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more code, this selector is valid. What i think you need to add is `display:block` to the label as this isn't a block level element.

```
 form.userform label {
      width: 150px;
      display: block;
 }
```

Now the width will be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below css code :

```
.userForm label {
    width: 150px;        
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

try it .

```
.userform fieldset div label {
    width: 150px;
}
```